# How to select a value with a column name that also needs selected?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

The SQL Server 2005 table I'm working from is really strange. Here's a simplified example:

```
 TABLE 1:
       key | a | b | c | d | e | f 
    z   0   1   2   3   4   5   6
    y   1   8   9  10  11  12  13
    x  14  15  16  17  18  19  20 
    w  21  22  23  24  25  26  27



TABLE 2:

  id | Value
     1    a
     2    b
     3    c
     4    e
     5    f
```

What I need to accomplish is to, in a single statement, select the column name from a different table, then get the value here. So it would be something like `"Select (select colName from table2 where id=VAR1) From table1 where key = VAR2"`
So table2 will return either a/b/c/d/e/f, and then the main statement will get the value of the corresponding value based on the key. 
Table2 will always return a-f, and I will know the VAR1 and VAR2 ahead of time.

Comment: You can do it using a `CASE` expression.

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos  Would I have to write a seperate clause for each column in table 1?

Comment: Yes, there is no other way (with static sql). Unless you want to use dymanic sql.

Comment: It would have been better, if you had provided the structure of both the tables and explain your variables such as `knownvar`. Only if you intend to receive a clear answer and perhaps more than one.

Comment: @bonCodigo I added a few details. I hope I'm being clear. I know the key ahead of time, and table 2 will always return a certain column name based on a value that I will know ahead of time.

Comment: Is there a known relationship between var1 and var2? If you include a table 2 example and the expected results, this would be helpful in understanding the requirement.

Comment: There seems to be a work-around using `UNPIVOT`. You can check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `UNPIVOT`:

```
SELECT [key], val, col
FROM 
  (SELECT [key], a, b, c, d, e, f
   FROM table1
   WHERE [key] = @var2) AS src
UNPIVOT
   (val FOR col IN 
      (a, b, c, d, e, f)
)AS unpvt
WHERE col = (SELECT value FROM table2 WHERE id = @var1)
```

`UNPIVOT` operation transposes table data from columns to rows creating an extra field where column name is placed. This way you can query table data using the name of the column that is obtained from `table2`.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/7ef0b/1)

Comment: I think this is exactly what I was thinking.